# algorithm to compare numbers within a certain distance from each other

Tags: iphone

So I have an array of numbers that look something like

```
1,708,234
2,802,532
11,083,432
5,098,123
5,777,111
```

I want to find out when two numbers are within a certain distance from each other (say 1,500,000) so I can group them into the same location and have just one UI element represent both for the level of zoom I am looking at.  How would one go about doing this smartly or efficiently.  I'm thinking I would just start with the first entry, loop through all the elements, and if one was close to another, flag those two and put it in a dictionary of some sort.  That would be my brute force method, but I'm thinking there has to be a better way.

I'm coding in obj-c btw if that makes or breaks any design decisions.

Comment: do you want to compare only direct neighbors in your table or all possible pairs of numbers?

Comment: This _might_ help:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering

Comment: @Thies Heidecke I want to compare all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many numbers are we dealing with here?  If it's small enough:

1. Sort the numbers (generally n-log-n)
2. Run through each number, n, and compare its bigger neighbor, n+1, to see if it's within your range.
3. Repeat for n+2, n+3, until the number is no longer within your range.

Your brute force method there is O((n/2)^2).  This method will bring it to O(n + n log(n)), or O(n log n) on the average case.

Comment: there aren't really that many numbers to sort.  Anywhere from 5-30.